# Front-end development with conditional HTTP and HTTPs routes

Tags: angularjs, http, https, frontend

I am currently using MEAN stack for web development. My questions is how do I mix/redirect HTTP and HTTPs pages on the same website?

For most scenarios I am communicating with the back-end using HTTP protocol.  And for some pages I **absolutely** need to use HTTP (For example ***/shop*** route I used a **iframe** that displays info from other websites. Also for some pages I need to HTTP GET from other API services providers.).  It seems that I cannot achieve these with HTTPs setup.

For some cases I am communicating with the back-end using HTTPs (such as ***/money*** route) ...etc. And apparently you need HTTPs with money involved.

My back-end has middlewares setup so that if you request ***/money*** using HTTP it will return some error (currently returning 301 moved permanently..)

But I am not sure how do I proceed with front-end development. For Angular part should I just do some configurations so when the route consists of /money I just reload the whole page in HTTPs and should I just explicitly make sure the links look someting like this?

```
<a ng-href="https://www.domain.com/#!/money">money page</a>
```

But that seems like a lot of hard-coding for me.

My question is: 
1. Am I thinking in the right direction?
2. Is it doable?

Thanks and any idea is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to consider here.

First of all, yes, when money is involved you should always use HTTPS. The S here stands for secure, so as you can imagine this means that regular HTTP is not secure. With regular HTTP things are sent in plain text, so anyone who can see the request along the way can see and copy what's in there. For this reason you should always make sure to use HTTPS if you are doing things like sending financials data, sending passwords/login requests, sending private user data, etc.

You should also remember that you shouldn't load HTTP content on a HTTPS page, this will cause browsers to warn for insecure content or even block the request outright.

Anyway, on to the actuall question. Yes, you are thinking correctly. When going from HTTP to HTTPS you are going to have to do a full reload of the page, but hardcoding https into any such link is not a great solution. Luckily Angular provides us with [decorators](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#decorator) for directives that allows us to chainge their behavior. You can use this to decorate ngHref so that it adds https on it's own when certain conditions are met.

Decorators are not that easy to get started with however, or at least they weren't the last time I read the docs, so here is one that does what you need and that you can edit to cover more cases:

```
myApp.config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('ngHrefDirective', function($delegate) {
      var original = $delegate[0].compile;
      $delegate[0].compile = function(element, attrs, transclude) {
        if(attrs.ngHref.indexOf('money') !== -1) {
            attrs.ngHref = 'https://example.com/'+attrs.ngHref;
        }
        return original(element, attrs, transclude);
      };
      return $delegate;
    })
});
```

This will take any ng-href directive that contains the word money, and change the input data to include the full path with https. It will turn this:

```
<a ng-href="/money">Link that should be re-written</a>
<a ng-href="/other">Link that should not be re-written</a>
```

Will become this:

```
<a href="https://example.com/money>Money link</a>
<a href="/other">Link that should not be re-written</a>
```

Comment: extremely helpful and I learned a lot from this.  I'll go verify the details and get back to you soon.  Thanks so much!

Comment: This works perfectly for ng-href links.   But if you get referred to https page with http links from other websites or from google you will still have to reload the entire page yourself is that correct?

Comment: Yes, in that case I would try to handle the rewrite in the server.